# MongoDB transactions and readPreference option

Tags: database, mongodb, transactions, nosql

Is there any way to use MongoDB multi-document transactions and `readPreference=secondaryPreferred` option at the same time? What is my goal: I have some functionality that makes a lot of heavy read operations, and I want to reduce the load from primary replica by executing read operations on secondary replicas.

MongoDB docs say that `readPreference` should be primary if transactions are used. So I am wondering how I can split load to read replicas. Does anyone know the way how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that because transactions can only be executed in the primary node. After the commit point, the operations are replicated in the secondary members too.

Transactions in MongoDB automatically guarantee *Read your own Writes* and *Monotonic Reads* (by design) in order to ensure a good level of consistency. Even if `readPreference=secondaryPreferred` was possible, these properties would not be granted and the results would be quite unpredictable. The safer way to implement transactions (in particular ACID properties) in a NoSQL DBMS is to pretend to be working on a single instance DB.

This does not mean you cannot have distributed transactions (in fact they exist in MongoDB), but a single source of truth is kind of necessary for each shard.

---

As @dododo pointed out, this is a restriction that they might relax in the future, as described in the [Driver Transactions Specification](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/transactions/transactions.rst#readpreference).

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/transactions/transactions.rst#readpreference It sounds like this restriction might be avoided, but as I know it still presents even in servers higher than 40

Comment: @dododo Interesting, thanks for that. I still think that relaxing that restriction would be too dangerous, trivially because you could read different versions of the same row if you try to read it multiple times. Thanks again for the link.

Comment: Thx. That’s what I expected to see. So, looks like the only way to achieve my goal - force application to perform read operations on secondary replicas.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [MongoDb Manual](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/core/transactions/#read-concern-write-concern-read-preference),

> If transaction-level and the session-level read preference are unset, the transaction uses the client-level read preference. By default, the client-level read preference is primary.

> Multi-document transactions that contain read operations must use read preference primary. All operations in a given transaction must route to the same member.

So coming to your question, I was able to update the read preferences for transactions using [TransactionOptions](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/com/mongodb/TransactionOptions.html) in the mongo configurations.

```
@Bean
MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDatabaseFactory dbFactory) {
    TransactionOptions transactionOptions = TransactionOptions.builder().readPreference(com.mongodb.ReadPreference.primary()).build());
    return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory, transactionOptions );
}
```

This worked for me. Thanks.